# Как избежать краша приложения в приставке Андроид ТВ?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Суть: есть приложение одного из интернет-провайдеров, соответственно и поставщика телевидения тоже, у него есть приложение, которое устанавливается на приставку IMAQLIQ и там уже и само телевидение и куча разных приложений внутри типа ютуб, мегого, ivi, всякие игры и тд. Когда вызываю приложение ютуб из нашего приложения и потом на пульте нажимаю на кнопку "назад", чтобы выйти из ютуба и вернуться в головное приложение провайдера головное приложение крашится, но не всегда, иногда этого не происходит. Из головного приложения в сторонние переход происходит через startactivity. Подозреваю, что проблема в том, что некоторые приложения жрут много памяти и сборщик удаляет главное приложение из памяти и вернуться по нажатию на кнопку " назад" тупо не к чему, активити удалено. Но я ведь не могу из приложения ютуб, ivi или мегого вызвать startactivity и стартануть его обратно, у меня ж нет доступа к коду этих приложений.

Вопрос: как выйти из этой ситуации? Может быть как то можно запретить сборщику удалять MainActivity принудительно?

P.s. приложение на Kotlin

Прошу камнями не закидывать, если вопрос тупой, я тут у вас новенький)) Заранее очень признателен каждому ответившему.

Comment: Не помешали бы логи креша. Тупиковых ситуаций типа: _"вернуться по нажатию на кнопку " назад" тупо не к чему"_ у Андроида быть не должно. Даже если таск пустой - открывается хомскрин. Если активность уничтожена системой ради освобождения памяти, то по возвращению к ней система запускает её с тем же интентом и сохранённым состоянием в `Bundle`. И вероятно она к такому не готова - то есть проблема в самой активности.

Comment: В логах креша написано, что toolbarPresenter не инициализирован. Приложение написано на паттерне MVP. Оно содержит одно активити, если не считать активити аутентификации, где пользователь просто логинится. Так вот, есть одно только MainActivity и куча фрагментов, toolbarFragment это один из фрагментов. Но все фрагменты, презентеры, адаптеры и все все все инициализируется при первом запуске приложения, в самом MainActivity, и все отлично работает, пока не начинаешь заходить в некоторые, именно некоторые сторонние приложения, инициализация пропадает сразу куда то. Логи будут в понедельник

Comment: 10:43:03.498 24114-24114/**.*******.television E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.profintel.television, PID: 24114
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mPresenter has not been initialized
        at **.********.television.components.toolbar.view.ToolbarCompFrag.getMPresenter(ToolbarCompFrag.kt:30)
        at **.********.television.components.toolbar.view.ToolbarCompFrag$onCreateView$2.invoke(ToolbarCompFrag.kt:40)
        at **.********.television.components.toolbar.view.ToolbarCompFrag$onCreateView$2.invoke(ToolbarCompFrag.kt:20)

Comment: Не надо в комменты - дополняйте вопрос (под ним есть кнопочка [`править`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/975342/edit)). И желательно добавить код - хотя бы кусок, на который ссылается ошибка. Хотя уже видно что в `ToolbarCompFrag` не проинициализирован презентер, но без кода не понять почему.